# Creating a SQL view with columns from other table records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with data like:

```
A1  FID  A2
0   0   39
1   0   23
0   1   16
1   1   64
2   1   12
0   2   76
0   3   11
0   4   87
```

And I want to create a view that will list this:

```
FID Col0 Col1 Col2
0    39   23  null
1    16   64   12
2    76  null null
3    11  null null
4    87  null null
```

How can this be possible in T-SQL?

Comment: Where is the other data (the other columns) coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT  FID,
        Col0 = MAX(CASE WHEN A1 = 0 THEN A2 END),
        Col1 = MAX(CASE WHEN A1 = 1 THEN A2 END),
        Col2 = MAX(CASE WHEN A1 = 2 THEN A2 END)
FROM    T
GROUP BY FID;
```

Or you could use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT  pvt.FID, 
        [Col0] = pvt.[0],
        [Col1] = pvt.[1],
        [Col2] = pvt.[2]
FROM    T
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(A2)
            FOR A1 IN ([0], [1], [2])
        ) pvt
```

**[Examples of Both on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5d01/1)**

If you have an unknown number of values for A1, and therefore an unknown number of columns you cannot do this in a view. You would need to use Dynamic SQL, although this is usually better handled in the application layer, not in SQL-Server itself

Comment: Thank you, that work, but now I have a problem for using the GroupBy.
Can you please check my latest question? Thank you.